# Evaluating sum of $\sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^{i/2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^{i/2} = (1+ \sqrt2)\left(2^{\frac{n+1}2} -1\right)$$

I know the above is true, but how would I get the right hand side? This summation shows up from a algorithm recurrence problem I have.

Comment: You know the sum formula for a geometric sum? Then note $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-1} = \sqrt{2} + 1.$$

Comment: @Mike BTW, try to use another alphabet for series, it makes confusion with complex number $i=\sqrt {-1}$

Comment: oh that's a good point. I'll try to use k's. My brain chose i from programming I guess. and then you got engineering reserving i for current lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n 2^{i/2}=\sum_{i=0}^n (\sqrt{2})^i,$$ 
i.e. a geometric series...

Answer (score 3):

As
$\sqrt 2 + 1 = \frac1 {\sqrt 2 - 1}
$
you should compute 
\begin{align}(\sqrt 2 - 1)\times
\sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^{i/2} &= \sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^{i/2}2^{1/2} - \sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^{i/2} 
\\&=  \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} 2^{i/2} - \sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^{i/2} 
\\&= 2^{(n+1)/2} - 1
\end{align}